# fastest way to assign range of integers from 0 to x to a container

Tags: c++, c++11

`x` is an unsigned integer. Runtime-wise, what's the fastest and most elegant  way to declare a container/initializer list filled with unsigned integers from 0 to `x`?

Ideally I'd like the solution to be a one-liner, something along the line of:

```
std::vector<int> v = {0..x};
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure about the performance:

```
std::vector<int> v(x);
std::generate_n(v.begin(), x, [] { static int i = -1; ++i; return i;});
```

Comment: [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota).

Comment: @user657267 daaaaamn my google-fu betrayed me once again, this is _exactly_ what I need! thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since C++11, there is a function in the C++ standard library that is made specifically for this: [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)